# Use sqlldr control file to automatically create several tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, import, sql-loader

I have a client who has a requirement that I load data from csv files into an Oracle database. Part of the requirement is that I use [sqlldr](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aLoader_FAQ) and provide a control file to facilitate loading this data. However there are a lot of text files with a lot of fields, and it will be a lot of labor to create the tables in the database and then create the control file for each table.

I know there are tools which will read a bunch of text files and generate the SQL that is required to create all the tables and load them with data. But that does not involve sqlldr with control file, which is the requirement. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: Just a note to say that SQL*Loader is considered obsolete; the modern way to do this is with external tables.

Answer (score 1):

The Utilities manual that describes SQL*Loader syntax (which no sane person can recall anyway!) has a number of case studies ([doc link here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL1011)). Case study 5 covers loading into multiple tables. The actual case studies are installed into $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/demo if you choose to install the companion CD. I seem to recall that in earlier versions they were also described in full in the Utilities manual.